# jQuery click event for differents a tags same class name

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the same click event for use a counter to add users. Also I have different `a` tags with same class name. I'm looking to increment once just on the tag that I'm clicking on. Thanks!

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a></p>
  </div><br><br>

  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a></p>
  </div><br><br>

  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var clicks = 0;
};

$(".sum").on("click", function() {
  clicks += 1;
  $(".clicks").html(clicks);
})
```

Comment: Could you post your JS code. It's not clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: What is the problem/question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get the element of what you clicked on. Then use `$(this).siblings("p").find("a")` to get the element we want to update.

I hope this is what you're looking for.

```js
$('.sum').click(function() {
  var count = $(this).siblings("p").find("a").text().split('/');
  var currentcount = (parseInt(count[0]) + 1);
  var maxcount = count[1];
  if (maxcount >= currentcount) {
    $(this).siblings("p").find("a").text(currentcount + "/" + maxcount)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"> <i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: @user3380738 Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use `this` to reference the `a` element that was clicked. From there you can traverse the DOM using `siblings()` and `find()` to get the `a` element whose text you want to update.

To make each count unique you'll need to dissect the text within the element and then increment it. Try this:

```js
$(".sum").on("click", function() {
  var $target = $(this).siblings('p').find('a');
  var values = $target.text().split('/');
  
  var clicks = parseInt(values[0], 10);
  var limit = parseInt(values[1], 10);
  
  if (clicks < limit) {
    clicks++;
    $target.text(clicks + '/' + limit);
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"> <i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="card-content">
    <a href="#" class="sum"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
    <p class="">
      Users <a class="clicks">0/20</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```